# Can we use specific padding patterns for AES to detect errors?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes, error-correction, error-detection

These days I have been reading and doing labs on AES. Say for 128-bit AES, during encryption, if the plaintext is less than 128 bits, then padding of all 0s will be added to it. After decryption these 0s can be removed.

I am thinking of using the padding for error detection: if the plaintext is always 16 bits, then after decryption the text should be in the form of (16 bits of some data + 112 bits of 0s). We call this form "Legal Plaintext". Totally there can be 2^16 legal plaintexts.

If an attacker does not know the Key and IV, by modifying the cipher the decrypted plaintext can be in any form. He/she has a probability of (2^16)/(2^128) = 2^(-112) to make it a legal plaintext, which is a very small chance.

Does this sound reasonable?

(of course the attacker can still do bit-flipping by modifying the ith cipher to get a wanted result in the (i+1)th plaintext)

Comment: This looks like a variant of a key check value (KCV). [Here is some reasoning](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1933/13022) why this is not worth the effort. Use authenticated encryption instead.

Answer (score 1):

There are well-designed [authenticated encryption modes,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption) like [GCM,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode) to detect errors (or tampering).

You don't state the mode in your scheme explicitly, but it sounds like you are proposing CBC. If so, it provides absolutely no protection at all: the attacker can flip any of the first 16 bits of cipher text and still have a valid plain text.

Comment: Do you mean that by flipping the first 16 bits of the current cipher, we will have the next block of plain text as valid? The plain text decrypted from the current cipher should still not be valid, right?

Comment: @adieux Right, I see what you mean. You'd detect the alteration on the current block and stop. Still, I'm not convinced of the security, and GCM is much more efficient, so what motivates this scheme?

Comment: Thanks. The reason why I brought this up is our channel is very slow and a message is sent every 3 secs. So I think just by using this simple way to check every time is good enough. Do you see any potential problems here?

Comment: @adieux By slow channel, do you mean your transmission speed is very low? If that's the case, then using 7/8 of your bandwidth for this seems wasteful. But if you just mean that your traffic is very low, of course that aspect won't matter. The main problem remaining is that, as a non-standard scheme, I wouldn't feel very confident about its security. A secondary concern is that you'll have to write more custom code to support the scheme, and implementation flaws are where exploits are found. A library implementing a standard mode like GCM will have better review and maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Padding with 0s (0x00) will nor work for binary data that may end with a 0x00 byte. Generally [PKCS#7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7) née PKCS#5 padding is used.
2. Combining padding with encryption authentication is a security violation for CBC mode encryption, see [padding oracle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_oracle_attack), and a bad idea in general. Keep encryption authentication and padding separate.
3. The IV is not consider secret and as a best practice is a random value prepended to the encrypted data. Using a non-random IV is a design flaw.

Many cryptographers have considered padding and encryption authentication and arrived at week better methods, it is best to follow these methods.

In general unless you are a cryptographic domain expert it is best not to try and come up with non-standard methods.

["Schneier's Law"](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html): Anyone, from the most clueless amateur to the best cryptographer, can create an algorithm that he himself can't break.

Comment: I got 1. and 3. Can you elaborate more on 2.? It should be very hard to modify the cipher to get the decrypted plaintext legal to authentication check. (I understand it can do to the next plaintext by bit-flipping though)